# unique positive real root fast computation

Tags: polynomials, na.numerical-analysis

What is the fastest way to compute the value of the unique positive real root corresponding to the following polynom:
 :p(x) = a*x^5 + b*x^4 + c*x^3 + d*x^2 + e*x - f = 0
where a, b, c, d, e, f are all strictly positive.
Please something faster or more subtle than newton...

Comment: You could use the observation that the root is less than the min of $(f/a_i)^{1/i}$ and greater than the max of $(f/5a_i)^{1/i}$, where I have relabelled the coefficients.  However, this is not subtle and at best I do not see how it will save much time or effort over using Newton-Raphson or even bisection.

Comment: Sorry: in both cases one needs min, not min and max.  Also, because the coefficients $a_i$ are all positive, you can restrict your attention to the appropriate roots of $ (f/5a_i)$ and use roots of $(f/a_i)$ only if it narrows the interval.

Comment: Do you have some reason, brian, to think there is something faster than Newton's Method?

Comment: there is the observation that the number exist and somehow easily bounded, hence I was thinking to some kind of magical number (expressed as a function of the coefficients exactly like Masked Avenger put forward) and then one or 2 round of newton...

Comment: to Masked Avenger: thanks that is a good starting point for the Newton. I see however a potential computation tradeoff : we might have to pay a lot computationnaly to compute the cubic roots compared to an uneducated guess and several more rounds of analytical Newton... this is where a need a kind of closed form for the solution or a nice but simple to compute guess to start the newton.

Comment: Since it is a guess, you can choose how cheap or sloppy to be at the start.  Also, in many cases the curve will be well approximated by a straight line, so when you get close to a zero, you can use a linear approximation and have a darned good idea of the error involved using little more than polynomial evaluation.

Comment: Is there anything you want to know that isn't covered in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method ?

Comment: The function is convex and monotone, so no guarding a la Brent or regula falsi is necessary. Halley's or Laguerre's method will be slightly faster than Newton's, as recently added to the linked above wikipedia article or with more detail in the article on the Householder methods.